# Include categories in search results - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am trying to include categories in search results,  if the keyword contain name of category it does not return any pages or posts related to  category's name is there any way to include category in search results?

this is the query I use

```
$args = array( 's' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'value' => $keyword,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )), 'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'value' => $keyword,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
), 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'orderby' => 'name title date', 'order' => $order, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'page');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Can you please properly format your code?

Comment: do you know any thing related?